# How to get all value from a custom atterbuite

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a list of all `id-data` value which is `5` and `10`. I already did like bellow but it seems this is not proper way to do this simple thing and this not works. the `console.log(value.attr("id-data")` not a proper function as console says. How to do it? I want to list of that 2 value and set it to `listOfIds` array.

Html & jquery

```js
var listOfIds = [];

var all = $(".productids").map(function() {
  return this.outerHTML;
}).get();

$.each(all, function(key, value) {
  console.log(value.attr("id-data"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='card productids' id-data='5'></div>
<div class='card productids' id-data='10'></div>
```

Comment: `listOfIds` is blank array with this code

Comment: Would it not be better to select elements with `[id-data]` instead of `.productids`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```js
var listOfIds = [];

$(".productids").each(function() {
  listOfIds.push($(this).attr("id-data"));
});
console.log(listOfIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='card productids' id-data='5'></div>
<div class='card productids' id-data='10'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do this:

```js
const listOfIds = [...$(".productids").map((i,d)=>
  $(d).attr("id-data"))];
console.log(listOfIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='card productids' id-data='5'></div>
<div class='card productids' id-data='10'></div>
```

The `[... jQueryObject]` construct is necessary to turn the result of `jQuery.map()` into an Array. Alternatively you can use one of the jQuery methods `.toArray()` and `.get()`.

You should avoid using arbitrary user-defined attributes in DOM elements. Instead the HTML5 attributes with names like `data-<name>` should be used. These can be accessed as `DOMElement.dataset[<name>]` (where `<name>` is a string).

```js
const listOfIds = $(".productids").get().map(d=>d.dataset.id);
console.log(listOfIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='card productids' data-id='5'></div>
<div class='card productids' data-id='10'></div>
```

In this last snippet I converted the jQuery selection itself into an array of DOM elements before applying `Array.prototype.map` on it.